# Is this situation better for Conditional formatting vs VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Currently stuck on trying to have cells automatically change colors depending on the text/date provided.

The process I’m supposed to have for each column is:

-Column O: if “y”= cell is green, “n”= cell is yellow

-Column P: if column O is “y” then cell is green, if column O is “n” then cell is yellow, if column O has a date then cell stays yellow, if column O has a date past due then cell is red.

The issue with this process is when a date is not immediately provided in column P, the cell turns red regardless. Ideally, if column O = “n” then column P should turn yellow with or without a date.

I’m having trouble on stating that the cell should ONLY turn red WHEN there is a date provided that is PAST DUE

Another issue with this process is despite column O = “y” green, the column P cell stays red rather than turning green in response to column O turning green. Ideally, if O= y= green then P = green with or without a date or past due date

I’ve tried conditionally formatting with the rules attached but it seems to either overlap eachother or overpower eachother in general. Just wondering if I should stick to conditional formatting or if I should do VBA.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Please edit your post to share conditionally formatting formula and sample data. The conditionally formatting could be an option.

Comment: Conditional formatting should work just fine in your case, just need to figure out the order of the rules and for example clarify `AND(ISDATE($P2),ISDATE($O2),$O2>$P2)` (if P-cell has due date) for the red coloring.

Comment: What about if the cell is empty then format as no colour...